# How to force HTML <video> to skip sources which can't be displayed as video?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I have an MP4 video encoded using a codec which Chrome seemingly doesn't support, because when I open the video in my browser it shows up as audio only.

I decided to account for videos like this in my application by generating a low-res H.264 version to be used when the primary codec isn't supported by the browser. I've got my `<video>` element set up like this:

```
<video>
    HTML video not supported
    <source src="original.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="display.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

However, Chrome doesn't ignore the first video despite not supporting the codec; it continues to display the entire `<video>` as audio only.

**Is there a way to force browsers to skip `<source>`s which cannot be displayed as video?**

If there's isn't a built-in way, how can I use JS to accomplish the same thing? I don't want to simply put `display.mp4` first because it is lower-resolution, which would not be optimal in cases where the browser can actually display the original. Would including the `codecs` portion of the content type fix this issue?

Comment: Could you link to such a file or at least specify which codec it is?

Comment: original.mp4 contains an MPEG-4 part 2 video stream; I didn't include the file because I'm experiencing the same problem with several other files (all with unsupported video codecs but AAC audio), and I would like a general solution to the problem.

Comment: Yes but that would help us to have such a file to try our solutions instead of having to guess.

Comment: I would really rather not upload the file as it is a video with my face in it. I am currently creating a test video which replicates my issue, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the codecs, you can call [`video.canPlayType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaytype):

```js
const supported = !!document.createElement("video")
  .canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="mp4v"');
console.log({ supported });
```

If you don't know that codec and have fixed files, you can check this website:
https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/mp4info/

If you don't have fixed files you can either retrieve the codecs with this library: https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js, or if you don't want to load this quite big amount of code, you can wait for the source to load and check that the `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` are zero:

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
video.play().then(() => {
  if(video.videoWidth + video.videoHeight === 0) {
    unsupported("video");
  }
}).catch(unsupported);

function unsupported(err) {
  console.error("unsupported", err);
}
```

```html
<video src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dj8g1oqu29zv8eh/mp4v.mp4" controls muted></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure [HTMLVideoElement.getVideoPlaybackQuality()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/getVideoPlaybackQuality) would help to judge whether the source has images or not, give it a try.

```
const isVideoSupport = yourVideoElement.getVideoPlaybackQuality().totalVideoFrames > 0;
```

Besides, if you already know which broswer can't play the 'origin' video, you can skip the video by checking out whether current browser is chrome/firefox/etc.